# index was out of range in asp.net gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i am creating a web app in which i have a gridview and on the pre-render method, i have following code

```
protected void dgvEdit_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.dgvEdit.EditIndex != -1)
            {
                FileUpload fp = (FileUpload)dgvEdit.Rows[dgvEdit.EditIndex].FindControl("fpTask");
                if (fp != null)
                {
                    // You can apply condition here
                    fp.Enabled = true;
                }

            }
        }
```

but the page is showing me the error

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out
>   of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the
>   collection. Parameter name: index

on this line

> Line 329:                FileUpload fp =
>   (FileUpload)dgvEdit.Rows[dgvEdit.EditIndex].FindControl("fpTask");

what is wrong with the following code

Comment: what is the value of `dgvEdit.EditIndex`

Comment: actually i dont know how to find the value of the gridview

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind showing this error is `dgvEdit.Rows.Count<dgvEdit.EditIndex` in `Line No 329`.

You can use a Condition like

```
if (this.dgvEdit.EditIndex != -1 && dgvEdit.Rows.Count>=dgvEdit.EditIndex)
            {
                FileUpload fp = (FileUpload)dgvEdit.Rows[dgvEdit.EditIndex].FindControl("fpTask");
                if (fp != null)
                {
                    // You can apply condition here
                    fp.Enabled = true;
                }

            }
```

N.B: Use `PreRender` event to perform any updates before the server control is rendered to the page. Any changes in the view state of the server control can be saved during this event. Such changes made in the rendering phase will not be saved.

I Think you should use `RowDataBound` for this.